# Call a PHP on the same file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file

I have a question: is there a way to call a php query from the same file?

Here is my code :

```
<?php 
function aggiungiPagine(){

    global $conn;

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $nomePagina = $_POST['nomePagina'];
    $descrizionePagina = $_POST['descrizione'];

    $comando = "select * from Pagine where Nome='$nomePagina'";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $comando); //trova tutti i risultati con quelle carateristiche
    $raws = mysqli_num_rows($query); //individua il numero di record trovati ed inseriti nella matrice $query

    if($raws == 0){ // controllo che non sia stato trovato l'utente
        $comando = "INSERT INTO Pagine (ID_Pagina,Tipo,Nome,Descrizione,Contenuto) VALUES (NULL,'Principale','$nomePagina','$descrizionePagina','')";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $comando)or die(mysqli_error());
        $error ="pagina inserita";
    }
    else{
        $error="Pagina con lo stesso nome gia trovata";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn); //chiudo la connessione col db
} ?>
```

and the js script in the same file :

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', "#btnAggPagPrinc", function(event) {
     $.post(aggiungiPagine(), $("#aggPagPrinc :input").serializeArray(), function(info){
        tappoOverlay();
        caricaPagPrinc();
    });
});
```

I use jQuery to post the data.

Sorry for bad English, I'm Italian

Comment: You really shouldn't do it that way. Using an AJAX function on the same file that you're working in could lead to disastrous results and will be hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: *"Sorry for bad english, i'm italian"* - No problema, io capito ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change jQuery POST request to `$.post('filename.php', data)`. AJAX request only invoke to URL requests.
2. AJAX request run action hidden under the URL (in your example it is filename.php). So if your php file has function inside, you must call its.
3. Add to the end of PHP file you just have to add `aggiungiPagine()` to call function.

Tip: Separate PHP code from Javascript code.

Tip: If you want to pass data from AJAX request to Javascript code, your php code must return some data (e.g. `echo` or `return`).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ajax` to post stuff.

```
<script>
  $("#btnAggPagPrinc").on('click', function(event) {
    var stuff = $("#aggPagPrinc :input").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'filename.php',
      data: stuff
    });
  });
</script>
```

and on your `PHP` page(no matter if it's the same page), do this.

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    aggiungiPagine();    //call your function
}
```